# Removing Microsoft Safelinks Trackers in Postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, microsoft-office-365

I'm receiving mail forwarded from MS/Office365 mail. Microsoft, bless their inquisitive soul (and I'm using bless in the broadest meaning possible), think it's a splendid idea to track all clicks on links in EMails under the guise of protecting users from malware and fraud. So they replace all links in the EMail with links to safelinks.protection.outlook.com (note the marketing theme?). The fact that they gather data on all clicks in forwarded emails as well as of their users is obviously an unintentional side effect like those Google & FaceBook beacons in sites. But I'm digressing.

I'm looking for a filter for PostFix that removes the safelinks envelope and replaces it with the original link.

Has anyone worked something like it yet?

Thanks.

Comment: do you use mailscanner, amavisd-new. spamassasin or something else (that has content filer built-in) If not, see this link as a starting point. https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail. 
Do some kind of regexp in the script...

Comment: Note that scanning mail body line-by-line can be very cpu/memory un-friendly